# Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: proof-explanation

Given $X$ a non-empty set and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with relation $\sim$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$: 
$$\forall A, B \subset X: A \sim B \Leftrightarrow A \Delta B \text{ is finite}$$

Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

I know that I have to prove that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. But I have no idea on how to start.

Comment: Good.  What does "$\sim$ is reflexive" mean in the context of this relation?

Comment: What’s $\Delta$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That means that $A \Delta A$ is finite. I am struggling to show that it is finite, which definition should I use to prove it?

Comment: @LucasHenrique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: By the definition of $\Delta$, $A\Delta A = \emptyset$, which is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the definition.  For reflexive, is $A \Delta A$ finite?  For symmetric, does $A \Delta B \text{ finite} \implies B\Delta A \text { finite}?$  The purpose of questions like this is to make sure you understand the definition.